# Is there a better way of simplifying fractions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, fractions

The way I teach my students to simplify fractions is to first write the numerator and denominator as a product of prime numbers, and then cancel.

For instance: $$\frac{15}{20} = \frac{3 \times 5}{2 \times 2 \times 5} = \frac{3}{2 \times 2} = \frac{3}{4}$$

This ensures that there aren't any "hidden" cancellations remaining that they've missed.

But sometimes, this is *really* inefficient. For instance:

$$\frac{42}{2} = \frac{2 \times 3 \times 7}{2} = 3 \times 7 = 21$$

The part where we factorized $21$ into $3 \times 7$ was obviously a complete waste of time: they should just have written

$$\frac{42}{2} = \frac{2 \times 21}{2} = 21$$

I'd like to find a better way of doing this, so I can be a better math tutor.

> **Question.** Is there a better way of simplifying fractions, that still ensures that the final result is in simplest form?

Comment: From a Student: Well, why not use the Euclidean Algorithim to find $\gcd(a,b)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the fraction $\displaystyle\frac ab$ then just find the $\gcd(a,b)$ and then cancel.

Comment: This seems like a good idea. I did not realize the Euclidean algorithm was actually an algorithm; I thought it was just a theorem.

Comment: @goblin Sir,in which class are the students you teach?

Comment: They're usually in Years 10 to 12, but some of the weaker ones need a brush up on fractions and basic arithmetic. Its remarkable how many Year 11 students can't add fractions, for example.

Comment: @goblin In Indian education system (as in my case) students are usually taught gcf and lcm around $9-10$ years....

Comment: Its possible that they're taught to 9-10 year olds here in Australia too, but that I just wasn't listening at the time. Perhaps here it is one of those things that is usually taught, but never tested.

Comment: Also: is the easiest way of finding $\mathrm{lcm}(a,b)$ to first find $\mathrm{gcd}(a,b)$ and then to compute $ab/\mathrm{gcd}(a,b)$? If not, what is the usual way of finding the lcm?

Comment: @goblin I use this method-http://www.math-only-math.com/to-find-least-common-multiple-by-using-division-method.html

Comment: Thanks. Is that a good website?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37958/discussion-between-tatan-and-goblin).